# How to assign custom cursors to entire website

Tags: asp.net, css, custom-cursor

I want to assign custom cursors to my entire website. I am using asp.net 4.0.

I have a master page and what I want is to assign a default custom cursor to the page and have all links use another custom cursor

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible yes. But please don't :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

makes the body one cursor type

```
body {
  cursor: url(path/to/cursor.ico) pointer;
}
```

makes your anchors another type

```
a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited{
  cursor: url(path/to/different_cursor.ico) pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSS`:

```
style="cursor: url(mycursor.cur), pointer;"
```

Note: Only .cur and .ani file types are supported as of IE6.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  cursor: url(path/to/cursor.cur), pointer;
}
```

[Further Reading](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/).

Answer (score 1):

If am understanding you correctly, You are looking to do something like this with css

```
body
{
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```